# Process.Start( "cmd.exe", argument1) Shows Command prompt in taskbar manager but not open Command prompt window on windows server

Tags: c#, windows, cmd, process.start

Process.Start( "cmd.exe", argument1) Shows Command prompt in task manager but not open Command prompt window on windows server R2.I test it locally it runs perfect and open Command prompt window  but when i host application on server its behaviour is strange .It shows Command prompt in taskbar manager but not open Command prompt window.I want to run exe file on server.Here is my code.

```
prc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prc.StartInfo.FileName ="cmd.exe";
prc.Start();
```

Comment: Well `prc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;` will hide the window ...

Comment: it works locally with this line .But i checked it by removing this line and also set false for CreateNoWindow. But still problem is same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

```
prc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prc.StartInfo.FileName ="cmd.exe";
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
prc.Start();
```

OR

```
prc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
prc.StartInfo.FileName ="cmd.exe";
prc.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
prc.Start();
```

To run the process without any window:

Using CreateNoWindow=true requires UseShellExecute=false

```
CreateNoWindow = true;
```

This can be changed on the fly:

To hide and show the window

```
WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing to the Stack Overflow community. This may be a correct answer, but it’d be really useful to provide additional explanation of your code so developers can understand your reasoning. This is especially useful for new developers who aren’t as familiar with the syntax or struggling to understand the concepts. **Would you kindly [edit] your answer to include additional details for the benefit of the community?**